# What is this patent (WO 2002/101622 A8) all about?

Tags: google-patents, wipo, wo2002101622a1, ca2456409a1, wo2002101622a8

In reference to the patent: [WO 2002/101622 A8](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2002101622A8)

Is there any link for detailed information about this patent? The abstract looks good but it would be great if there is any link to get detailed information.

Answer (score 2):

The 'A8' part of this patent document identifier is the [Kind Code](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/help?locale=en_EP&method=handleHelpTopic&topic=kindcodes) (the "kind of document"), which in this case indicates that the document is a correction to the title page of the application:

[WO 2002/101622 A8](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2002101622A8)

What you are looking for is the 'A1' document (the published patent application itself):

[WO 2002/101622 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2002101622A1)

Note the 'Also published as ...' lists several documents, including the [CA 2,456,409 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2456409A1) being the Canadian application, which should be similar if not identical to the WIPO application.